# Subfigure with vertically centered subcaptions on the side

Tags: subcaption, parbox

I am trying to have multiple subfigures in rows with their respective subcation on the left side of them. I found a useful answer on the LaTeX forums using `\parbox`, but the subcaptions are not vertically centered, even though I put `c` as the position parameter. I guess it is because the first subcaption-parbox is not the same height dimension as the graphics-parbox. How can I achieve that?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{slc=off,margin={1cm,0cm}}
  \parbox[m]{0.4\textwidth}{\subcaption{A subfigure}}
  \parbox[b]{0.5\textwidth}{\includegraphics[width=\hsize]{image1}}\\
  \parbox[m]{0.4\textwidth}{\subcaption{Another subfigure}}
  \parbox[b]{0.5\textwidth}{\includegraphics[width=\hsize]{image3}}\\
  \parbox[m]{0.4\textwidth}{\subcaption{A third subfigure}}
  \parbox[b]{0.5\textwidth}{\includegraphics[width=\hsize]{image3}}\\
  \caption{A collection of subfigures}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I am also open for other suggestions that doesn't include `\parbox`.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: My guess is that the `floatrow` package can answer your question. Take a look at its manual pages 68 onward. I will see if I can make a MWE using that package a bit later on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The middle alignment should work if you want the middle alignment but you would also need to adjust a baseline of each image for the top or the bottom alignments.

Therefore, I would additionally load `adjustbox` package with an extra optional argument `valign`, which controls baselines--make sure you add package option `[export]`.

Optional `justification=...` of `\captionsetup` controls horizontal alignment of captions; it accepts `raggedright`, `raggedleft`, or `centering` among of others.

Here's slightly changed code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\usepackage{xcolor}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[tbh]
  \setkeys{Gin}{width=0.5\linewidth}
  \captionsetup{position=bottom,skip=15pt}
  \captionsetup[subfigure]{
    justification=raggedright,
    singlelinecheck=no,
    format=hang,
    belowskip=0pt,
    aboveskip=0pt,
    %margin={1cm,0cm},
  }
  \centering
  \begin{subcaptiongroup}
    \parbox[t]{0.4\textwidth}{\caption{A subfigure}}%
    \hspace{1em}%
    \includegraphics[valign=T]{image1}

    \bigskip
    
    \parbox{0.4\textwidth}{\caption{Another subfigure. Another subfigure. Another subfigure}}%
    \hspace{1em}%
    \includegraphics[valign=c]{image3}
    
    \bigskip

    \parbox[b]{0.4\textwidth}{\caption{A third subfigure}}%
    \hspace{1em}%
    \includegraphics[valign=B]{image3}
    \par
  \end{subcaptiongroup}
  \caption{A collection of subfigures}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: what about the vertical centering of all captions? In your answer only the middle one is vertically centered.

Comment: I know, it's just for demonstration if OP would like to compare code corresponding to each case.

Comment: Ah .. check! Understood

Comment: My LaTeX is not happy about the "subcaptiongroup" environment, I am not sure where you got that from, and I am not sure what the "\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}" does. Regardless, it works without it, thank you, and the middle example is perfect. Thank you

Comment: `subcaptiongroup` merely affect regular `\caption` labels as if `\subcaption` was used. Other than that, it does nothing! I don't know the reason of your issues; it might be worth looking at the log. Because your layout is heavily customised with `parbox`es, I thought it might be easier to apply regular macros inside `subcaptiongroup`. This is a legit environment (see section 4 of [documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption)).

Comment: `\setkeys{Gin}{...}` on the other hand is to avoid repetition when applying the same settings to each image (see section 4.6 of [graphicx documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx)). It has a global scope unless used inside a group, such as `figure` environment. Then, all figures in such environment receive its settings.

Answer (score 3):

This code should do what you are looking for:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{justification=centerlast}

\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[subfigure]{style=BOXED,capbesideposition={left,center}} % change style to style=plain to remove the boxes

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{figure}
            \ffigbox
            {
            \begin{subfloatrow}
                \fcapside[\FBwidth]{\caption{A subfigure}}{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example=image-a.png}}
            \end{subfloatrow}   
            \begin{subfloatrow}
                \fcapside[\FBwidth]{\caption{A subfigure}}{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example=image-a.png}}
            \end{subfloatrow}
            \begin{subfloatrow}
                \fcapside[\FBwidth]{\caption{A subfigure}}{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example=image-a.png}}
            \end{subfloatrow}
            }
            {\caption{A collection of subfigures}}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: caption beside figure]

Comment: Thanks for your response. I didn't specify this in my question, but I have other subfigure environments which layout I am happy about. This was only one figure that I wanted to have this specific layout. I found a way to hardcode this in by adding a height and inner-position parameter in the parbox command.