# One figure next to the other in LaTeX, in a particular case

Tags: figure-placement

I have written the following code in LaTeX which produces what is in the image below. My question is, how can I make it so that the two figures are in the same row, one next to the other?
I have tried using minipage and subfigure but could not work it out. Thanks!

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\minipage{0.1\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[trim={0 2 2 2},clip,width=\linewidth]{image1.jpg}
\endminipage
\hspace{1 cm}
\minipage{0.1\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[trim={0 2 2 2},clip,width=\linewidth]{image2.jpg}
\endminipage
\caption{1st common caption}
\label{1st label}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\minipage{0.1\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[trim={0 2 2 2},clip,width=\linewidth]{image3.jpg}
\endminipage
\hspace{1 cm}
\minipage{0.1\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[trim={0 2 2 2},clip,width=\linewidth]{image4.jpg}
\endminipage
\caption{2nd common caption}
\label{2nd label}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

[image: This is what the code produces]

This is what I would like:
[image]

Comment: put them together in one figure environment.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks, I tried. But if I add \begin{figure} and \end{figure} at the top and bottom of the code, the error "Not in outer par mode" appears. If I remove the \end{figure} and \begin{figure} right in the middle of the code, the problem isn't solved; the two figures get closer together.

Comment: you can always add space between both e.g. with \vspace.

Comment: Take a look at the options in the `floatrow` package. An example of using that package to obtain a desired output can be found here:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/674888/subfigure-with-vertically-centered-subcaptions-on-the-side/674897#674897. There are other examples available too, I guess.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, the thing is that they are still one below the other (not next to the other). I edited my post to show the desired result.

Comment: @alchemist Thanks! It looks like it is indeed possible to do it with floatrow (http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/floatrow/floatrow.pdf, page 101), but I think @\egreg found a simpler way.

Comment: sorry it wasn't clear that you want them side by side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never use `\minipage` and `\endminipage` inside `document`. The two commands can be used for defining a new environment.

Now you can do the job using `minipages`, but in a different way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering

\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\centering

\includegraphics[width=0.25\linewidth]{example-image-9x16}%
\hspace{1cm}%
\includegraphics[width=0.25\linewidth]{example-image-9x16}%

\caption{1st common caption}
\label{1st label}

\end{minipage}%
\hspace{2cm}%
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\centering

\includegraphics[width=0.25\linewidth]{example-image-9x16}%
\hspace{1cm}%
\includegraphics[width=0.25\linewidth]{example-image-9x16}%

\caption{2nd common caption}
\label{2nd label}

\end{minipage}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, that solved it perfectly ;)